# Excel 2010 Slicers errors with parameter names

Tags: excel, vba, parameters

SlicersCaches.add and Slicers.Add gives error when I name the parameters but works fine without.

Error:

```
Set SC1 = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add(Source:=PivTable Sourcefield:="Dept")
Set SL1 = SC1.Slicers.Add(Slicerdestination:=PivSheet)
```

No Error:

```
Set SC1 = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add(PivTable, "Dept")
Set SL1 = SC1.Slicers.Add(PivSheet)
```

Is this a bug in the program?

Answer (score 1):

There are no bugs in the program. When you call a Sub or Function procedure, you can supply arguments positionally, in the order they appear in the procedure's definition, or you can supply the arguments by name without regard to position.

Named arguments are especially useful when you are calling a procedure that has optional arguments. If you use named arguments, you don't have to include commas to denote missing positional arguments. Using named arguments makes it easier to keep track of which arguments you passed and which you omitted.

When you call a procedure with an optional argument, you can choose whether or not to specify the optional argument. If you don't specify the optional argument, the default value, if any, is used. If no default value is specified, the argument is it would be for any variable of the specified type.

Below are the complete definitions of the slicer functions with arguments (optional in square brackets):

1. Slicer.Add

   Add(SlicerDestination, [Level], [Name], [Caption], [Top], [Left], [Width], [Height]) As Slicer
2. SlicerCache.Add

   Add(Source, SourceField, [Name]) As SlicerCache